# Why excel Indirect reference to Table data doesnt work

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Any idea why the following doesnt work with indirect function?

[image]

I tried referencing a cell with the syntax of getting table [HEADER_B] in row 2:2 within indirect function in another cell, it also didnt work.
Example:
Table1[HEADER_B] 2:2

But '=Table1[HEADER_B] 2:2' itself worked

Comment: What is the use case for this indirect-usage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use one `INDIRECT` per each range:

```
=INDIRECT("Table1[Header_B]") INDIRECT("2:2")
```